# wxpython how to find a wx.ListCtrl range

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have created an appliation in wxpython and I have a simple ListCtrl and I want to find out how many values this listrctl has because the number of the values are not standard. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ListCtrl-class.html):

[`wx.ListCtrl.GetColumnCount()`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ListCtrl-class.html#ColumnCount)

[`wx.ListCtrl.GetItemCount()`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ListCtrl-class.html#ItemCount)

What do you mean by not standard?

Comment: My guess is that the number of items varies.